# Trouble with l'Hôpital's rule for $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+4\sin x}{10x+10\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

This is an assignment and I am stuck:

> Find the limit, whether finite or infinite, or indicate that the limit does not exist. Use l'Hôpital's Rule if appropriate.
>
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+4\sin x}{10x+10\cos x}.$$

When I try l'Hôpital's rule I get $\frac 8{10}$. Can someone tell me why this isn't right?

Comment: sorry I will type it when it preview it showed the image so i thought it would work

Comment: @amWhy I fixed it. It was just a .png. For OP: Try dividing everything by $x$ and recalling that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: yeah thanks this site is a bit of a pain sorry about that

Comment: _If_ the limit of the numerator f (x) is 0 (inf) _and_ the limit of the denominator g (x) is also 0 (inf) _and_ the limit of f' (x) / g' (x) exists, then the limit of f (x) / g (x) exists and is the same. Which of the three conditions fails?

Comment: Check again the prerequisities to  l'Hôpital's rule. Do expressions above and below the fraction line satisfy them? And – do you really need the rule at all? How about just _calculating_ the subexpressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Original posted question:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+4\sin x}{10x+10\sin x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(4x + 4\sin x)'}{(10x + 10 \sin x)'} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4+4\cos x}{10 + 10\cos x} = \frac {4 + 4}{10 + 10} = \frac {8}{20} = \frac 25$$

---

**Since you meant to post** $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+4\sin x}{10x+10\cos x}$$ note that in this case, l'Hôpital is not applicable (the limit does not at first evaluate to an indeterminate limit). Nor would we want to use it! It is easily solved by evaluating immediately:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+4\sin x}{10x+10\cos x} = \frac{ 0 + 0}{0 + 10(1)} = \frac {0}{10} = 0$$

IMPORTANT TO REMEMBER: We apply l'Hôpital's rule if and only if a limit evaluates to an **[indeterminate form.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms)** That bold-face link will take you to Wikipedia's concise list of "what counts" as an indeterminate form, and why.

Comment: the bottom was cos not sin

Comment: I've updated, wolfcall, now that the original question has been corrected! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just plug in! The denominator is $10$, not zero. ;)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: No problem! You should accept one of the answers (either mine or amWhy's).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a non-rigorous approach but here you go :

When $x\to 0$ we have these two approximations :

$$\sin x \overset{x\to 0}\sim x \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \  \cos(x) \overset{x\to 0}\sim 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$
Let :

$$\mathcal{L} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+4\sin x}{10x+10\cos x}$$
Using those approximations we get :
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4x+4x}{10x-10-5x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{8x}{-5x^2+10x-10}\\
&= \frac{0}{10}\\
&=0
\end{align}
Your limit doesn't need anything it's already equals $0$ without direct substitutions.